# Is there any way to disable or adjust request timeout in Chrome or Opera like in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

In firefox it's easy to disable request timeout in about:config is there anyway to do it in chrome or opera or any chromium based browser?

There is an over crowded website I deal with daily in my job. in firefox after I disabled the timeout it loads for 3 to 5 minutes then gives me what I want but in the case of chrome it quits and gives me connection timeout after less than a minute and I can't use firefox for different reasons.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? Chrome does have [flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) including a [`--timeout`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#timeout), but it's unclear why you want to do this and therefore whether that would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "but it's unclear why you want to do this and therefore whether that would be helpful." -- There's no need to know why someone wants to do something - just answer the question.

This works for us:

Look for network.http.connection-timeout as seen in the above image. By default, it is set to 90 seconds. If you would like to change the value, double-click on the value or click the edit button and enter your new value. Press Enter or click the Save button.

If you would like to change the timeout duration of retry attempts, similarly edit the value for network.http.connection-retry-timeout and save it. Your new Firefox network connection timeout settings are active now.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This question asks a solution for _Chromium-based browsers_!